# Highlighting only ONE <tr> in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need it so when you click on a table row it highlights only that ONE row in the table, if the user was to click another TR from the same table it will deselect the previously selected TR and highlight the clicked one.

Help?

What im using now is

```
<tr onclick="style.backgroundColor='#eaf0f5';"> ..... </tr>
```

Comment: did you try anything yet? where's your code?

Comment: A the moment all i have is onclick="style.backgroundColor='#eaf0f5';" inside the <tr>

Comment: Use jQuery. Here you have the api docs: http://api.jquery.com/
You may want to have a look at selectors :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

jQuery 1.7+

```
$("table tr").on('click', function() {
    $("table tr").removeClass("highlight");
    $(this).addClass("highlight");
});
```

jQuery <1.7

```
$("table tr").click(function() {
    $("table tr").removeClass("highlight");
    $(this).addClass("highlight");
});
```

CSS

```
.highlight { background-color: #FF0; }
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method on

Comment: I guess you're using an older version of jQuery, I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thanks no errors now but when i click on a TR it navigates me to another tab like it should but when i go back to the original tab it is not highlighted, i have the .highlight in my css

Comment: @Ahmet if the link goes to another page then you will need to use cookies to persist the state of the highlight for each table.

Comment: Is there no other way? it's not like im navigating to another page. onclick="backgroundcolour" works but it stays highlighted once clicked

Comment: Also its not working for my tabs that DONT link to another page